# IEEE 754 Floating Point Representation addition sum exceeds places in 16 bit format

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, 16-bit

I have two floating point numbers in 16 bit binary notation, and when I'm trying to add them I stumble across an issue:

```
A = 0  11110  1111000000    
B = 0  11010  1101110000
```

Now A+B is what I'm trying to do, but here's my problem; How do I represent the sum in 16 bit format?

A = 63488

B = 3808

A+B = 67296

The maximum decimal number that can be fit into 16 bits in IEEE 754 notation is 65504, being represented:

```
MAX = 0 11110 1111111111 = 65504
```

How do I represent 67296?

Comment: AFAICT, you can't. You have an overflow.

Comment: If you are following IEEE 754, the result is positive infinity, `0  11111  0000000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to calculate `A+B` for:

```
A = 0  11110  1111_0000_00    
B = 0  11010  1101_1100_00
```

Making the leading one bits explicit and adjusting to the same exponent:

```
A = 0  11110  1.1111_0000_00    
B = 0  11110  0.0001_1101_11
```

Adding:

```
A + B = 0  11110  10.0000_1101_11
```

Normalizing, ignoring exponent overflow:

```
A + B = 0  11111  1.0000_0110_111
```

Round to nearest, still ignoring exponent overflow:

```
A + B = 0  11111  1.0000_0111_00
```

The exponent after rounding is too big to store as a normal number. The sum is positive, so the result is positive infinity:

```
A + B = 0  11111  0000_0000_00
```

Answer (score 0):

Also! Another answer is NaN (Not a Number) when the exponent is all ones and the fraction differs from zero!

Comment: That does seem like a more accurate answer than just concluding that it becomes infinity!